# Why does C-x C-f in emacs just switch among several windows?

Tags: emacs

I'm new to emacs. I want to use C-x C-f to open .emacs file, but what emacs does is just switching among "GUN Emacs", "test.sml", "Messages", "sml" and "scratch". I don't even have chance to enter the file name in the bottom.

Comment: If you type `C-h k C-x C-f`, what does the `*Help*` buffer say is the name of the function you just called?  It should say `find-file`, unless you have changed the default settings somehow.  In the world of Emacs, we use the capital letter `C` to indicate Control -- please edit your title and the body of your question to reflect the capital letter `C` unless you *really* meant the literal letter lowercase `c`.

Comment: @lawlist, it shows following "C-x <right> runs the command next-buffer, which is an interactive
compiled Lisp function in `window.el'.

It is bound to <XF86Forward>, C-x <C-right>, C-x <right>, <menu-bar>
<buffer> <next-buffer>.

(next-buffer)

In selected window switch to next buffer."

Comment: Then you have altered the default behavior of Emacs somewhere in your setup.  You may need to comment out sections of your user-configuration and restart Emacs until you isolate where it is that you messed up.  You can verify the default setup by starting with **emacs -q** -- i.e., no user configuration.  You might want to look for something in your setup that deals with `next-buffer`, and perhaps you can find it with a simple word-search / grep.  In the early days, I once misplaced a closing parenthesis and had several functions stuck together by mistake.  Commenting stuff out may be easiest.

Comment: What platform are you running on? Are you running emacs in a terminal, or in a window? The response to `C-h k C-x C-f` seems to indicate that emacs can't tell the difference between `C-f` and `<right>`, which is the right arrow key. Did you remap your keyboard outside of emacs somewhere?

Comment: Is there anyway I can reset my key binding to default key binding?

Comment: As @lawlist suggested - run **emacs -q**, then check `C-h k C-x C-f` again. If it shows the same - the problem is outside of emacs, something in your environment is mapping `C-f` to `<right>`. If on the other hand you get `find-files` as it is supposed to be, then it's your emacs config acting up.

Comment: Thank you, @lawlist @Yuri. I found the problem is that I use betterTouchTool to map `C-f` to move right.